# Uncaught ReferenceError in my little script

Tags: javascript, function

I have a little simple JavaScript. And it works. but if I change the function name I get an error

My HTML page is:

```html
<input type="number" name="getal" id="number" placeholder="Getal 1"><br>
<div id="operator">+</div>

<input type="number" name="getal1" id="number1" placeholder="Getal 2"><br>
<br>
<button id="btn" onclick="som()">=</button>

<p>

<div id="total">
      
  </div>
```

And the JavaScript is

```
function som(){
  //Scherm leeg te maken.
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "";
  //Nummer van input ophalen
  var x = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var num1 = parseFloat (x);
  var num2 = parseFloat (y);
  var z = num1 + num2;

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = num1 +" + "+ num2 +" = "+ z ;
  // Reset van het input de velden.
  document.getElementById("number").value = "";
  document.getElementById("number1").value = "";
}
```

This little script is working.

Now I change only the name of the onclick and the function.

In the HTML file

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="som1()">=</button>
```

And in the Script

```
function som1()
```

But now I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: som1 is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (som.html:17)

Can someone tell me what I'm actually doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps a stupid question, but are you sure you saved the new script after the change? And if you did, it could be being cached by your browser. Try control and F5 to clear the cache and reload. Otherwise I don't see how you would get this particular error if you've done as you said.

Comment: PS while not the direct cause of this issue, `onclick="somefunction()"` is not a very good idea, for a variety of reasons. You're better off using the `addEventListener` method to attach event handlers inside your Javascript.

Comment: Hello, yes my software is standing on AutoSave.  About not to use onlclick but addEventListener, I will this take with me, thanks for this kind of tip. I wil try to change my code with it..

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of the .js file that contains your som1 function:

```
window.som1 = som1;
```